# Company Name throughout document from popup window

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Using the following I was able to perfectly add the information I need to a document.  However, I have multiple places the company name needs to go in the document.  The bookmark won't allow me to have the same one twice.  Is there a way to add like ("CompanyName1") to populate the same answer to the "Enter Company Name Here" WITHOUT having to fill out another window?

```
Sub Document_Open()

     ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompanyName").Result = InputBox("Enter company name here")
     ActiveDocument.FormFields("CompanyStreet").Result = InputBox("Enter the company's street address here")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use as StyleRef field. It works by assigning the original location where the Company Name, or Person's Name, or ... each a unique Style Name such as "TheCompanyName". Then in the locations where you want the value of "TheCompanyName" inserted, you insert a StyleRef field that specifies the Style Name to use.

Below is a screen clip from a document that is using the title of the document, which on the cover page and repeating it later in the document. The Style Name in this example is "LGP Program Name". I have toggled on the field code so you could see how it's constructed.

[image]

The image below shows how it actually looks in the document.

[image]